# Select count of specific values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQL table with some values.

```
NAME            ELEMENT
122601:1ZIN:AP5|N
122601:1ZIN:AP5|N
122601:1ZIN:AP5|C
122601:1ZIN:AP5|N
122601:1ZIN:AP5|N
122601:1ZIN:AP5|N
123440:1ZPD:CIT|C
123440:1ZPD:CIT|O
123440:1ZPD:CIT|O
123440:1ZPD:CIT|C
123440:1ZPD:CIT|C
123440:1ZPD:CIT|O
123440:1ZPD:CIT|O
123440:1ZPD:CIT|C
```

How can I select only those names where counts of C's and O's are greater than 2, for example? and where there are nothing than C and O?

Comment: What does _"and where there are nothing than C and O?"_ mean?

Comment: It means that we want to select only those rows where ELEMENT==C or ELEMENT==O

Comment: @annndrey: Can you add the result you want? And what you have tried?

Comment: From this table I'd like to get only 123440:1ZPD:CIT because it contains only C and O. Now I'm retrieving my data by a python script, but I'd like to know if it can be done more easy in SQL, so I've converted my data to sqlite and have posted my question here.

Comment: @annndrey. are you still having problems?

Comment: And if there was one more with `122601:1ZIN:AP5|C`? Should `122601:1ZIN:AP5` be shown then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ought to do it for you:

```
SELECT NAME FROM TABLE WHERE ELEMENT IN (SELECT ELEMENT                  
FROM TABLE WHERE ELEMENT IN('C', 'O') GROUP BY ELEMENT                  
HAVING COUNT(ELEMENT) > 2)
```

Comment: @gdoron: This has `SELECT Element`, yours has `SELECT Name`.

Comment: @ypercube...I don't understand your comment.  I believe that annndrey wants to select the name.

Comment: Yes, the goal is to retrieve the name with specific occurencies if specific elements

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.NAME
FROM TABLE_NAME T
WHERE T.ELEMENT IN (SELECT TT.ELEMENT
                    FROM TABLE_NAME TT
                    WHERE TT.ELEMENT IN ('C', 'O')
                    GROUP BY TT.ELEMENT
                    HAVING COUNT(TT.ELEMENT) > 2)
```

Comment: **why the down vote?** if you downvoted without a comment, you didn't do anything but loosing one rep point...

Comment: @won't this error out since TT.Name is not in the Group By list?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if these are the most optimised but...

Where there are more than 2 C's

```
SELECT NAME, LENGTH(ELEMENT) - LENGTH(REPLACE(ELEMENT, 'C', '')) as countC FROM table HAVING countC > 2;
```

Only C and O's in the element

```
SELECT NAME, ELEMENT REGEXP "^[CO]+$" AS hasCO FROM table having hasCO = 1;
```

Not tested them but i think they are right